# Moving and copying multiple files

Tags: r, file-manipulation

I will have list of source path & destination path in excel,

How can I move these files

| source | destination |
| --- | --- |
| C:/users/desk/1/a.pdf | C:/users/desktop/2 |
| C:/users/desk/1/b.pdf | C:/users/desktop/3 |
| C:/users/desk/1/abb.pdf | C:/users/desktop/56 |

I need to copy a file from particular source to respective given destination.

Answer (score 1):

To *copy* the files, you can use [`file.copy`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files). This accepts a <s>vector of</s> *single* directory, or a vector of file paths as destinations, and copies the files to the new directory/paths.

As your destination column contains only directory paths, you need to specify full paths (including file names) for new files. To do this, you can use [`file.path`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/file.path) and [`basename`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/basename) to concatenate the original file names (in `source`) to the new directories (`destination`).

```r
df = data.frame(
  source = c('C:/users/desk/1/a.pdf', 'C:/users/desk/1/b.pdf', 'C:/users/desk/1/abb.pdf'),
  destination = c('C:/users/desktop/2', 'C:/users/desktop/3', 'C:/users/desktop/56')
)
file.copy(from = df$source, to = file.path(df$destination, basename(df$source)))
```

To *move* the files, you can use [`file.rename`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files).

```r
file.rename(from = df$source, to = file.path(df$destination, basename(df$source)))
```

**Note 1:** `file.rename` may only work when moving files between locations on the same drive. To move files across drives you could use `file.copy` followed by `file.remove` to remove the original files after copying. If doing this, you should be careful not to remove files if the copy operation fails, e.g.:

```r
file.move <- function(from, to, ...) {
  # copy files and store vector of success
  cp <- file.copy(from = from, to = to, ...)

  # remove those files that were successful
  file.remove(from[cp])

  # warn about unsuccessful files
  if (any(!cp)) {
    warning(
      'The following files could not be moved:\n', 
      paste(from[!cp], collapse = '\n')
    )
  }
}

file.move(from = df$source, to = file.path(df$destination, basename(df$source)))
```

**Note 2:** This is all assuming that you have read in your excel data using one of [`read.csv`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table) or [`data.table::fread`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/fread) (for `.csv` files) or [`readxl::read_excel`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readxl/versions/1.3.1/topics/read_excel) (for `.xls` or `.xlsx` files)

Comment: This code is not working, multiple files not moving/copying, getting false at end of the output

Comment: @HemachandSrinivasan Apologies, apparently `file.copy` only accepts a single directory, or a vector of complete paths. I have amended my answer to reflect this.