# How to move files in a other folder with base on a df list

Tags: r, tidyverse, file-manipulation, movefile

I'm download 20.000 files .png and put in order to specific folder name. Each folder has 1 or 2 .png files.

link of example:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1di8b1L1i1lc2ZKTAWyrNiZNpxMmGcQAH?usp=share_link

```
order_NEW<- data.frame(ACCESION=c('G    1','G    7A', 'G35015', 'G40897','G27573'),
                    FOLDER= c( 'P_vulgaris', 'P_vulgaris','P_dumosus', 'P_albescens', 
                               'P_lunatus'))
```

In `order_NEW` of **FOLDER** I'm want create this folders that contain 2 other folders, for `sed` and `pod` but depend of **FOLDER** name.

For example the **FOLDER** *P_vulgaris* is necessary create 2 others folders, `sed` and `pod`. In `sed` folder I'm want put the sed picture of G 1 and `pod` folder put the pod picture.

I have the folders in this form:

[image]

The folders contais this type of pictures:
[image]

The idea is move the files in other folder, but depend of **order_NEW** df.

[image]

Comment: A R user try to help me in other forum:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/move-files-in-a-specific-folder-with-df-list/152365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im find this solution. Maybe dont is the most easy but for now is well for me. Sahe with us.

1. Get the names of directories

   ```
   main_dir <- ('C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2')
   dir_list <- as.data.frame(list.dirs(main_dir,recursive = T))   
   1     C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   57
   3     C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   76
   4     C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   87
   5     C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   92
   6     C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  148
   7     C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  166
   ```
2. Get only the folder name

   ```
    dir_list2 <- as.data.frame(list.dirs(main_dir,recursive = T,full.names = 
     FALSE)) 
        2                                                    G   57
        3                                                    G   76
        4                                                    G   87
        5                                                    G   92
        6                                                    G  148
        7                                                    G  166
   ```
3. Merge the names and add to .jpg format (the pictures files has the same names of each folder)

   ```
    dir_list$NEW <- paste0(dir_list$`list.dirs(main_dir, recursive = T)`,"\\",
                       dir_list2$`list.dirs(main_dir, recursive = T, full.names = FALSE)` ," ", "seed.jpg")

   # [2] "C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   57\\G   57 seed.jpg"  
   # [3] "C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   76\\G   76 seed.jpg"  
   # [4] "C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   87\\G   87 seed.jpg"  
   # [5] "C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   92\\G   92 seed.jpg"  
   # [6] "C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  148\\G  148 seed.jpg"  
   # [7] "C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  166\\G  166 seed.jpg"
   ```
4. Im filter the names of each ACCESION in each FOLDER. And create in manual form each one. And in each one the two other folder, seed and pod.

[image]

5. Fit the names for use in a function. Add ' in start and final of each path, , for separate each one.

   ```
   dir_list$NEW<- paste0("'", dir_list$NEW,"'", ",")

   # I have problems with \\ and \. But is easy to change with replace tools of 
   Rstudio.
   # [2] "'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   76\\G   76 seed.jpg',"  
   # [3] "'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   87\\G   87 seed.jpg',"  
   # [4] "'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   92\\G   92 seed.jpg',"  
   # [5] "'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  148\\G  148 seed.jpg',"  
   # [6] "'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  166\\G  166 seed.jpg',"  
   # [7] "'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  169\\G  169 seed.jpg'"  
    #delete the (,) in final object.
   ```
6. Run this code

   ```
   # Im use this example 
   # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601557/moving-and-copying-multiple- 
     files
   df = data.frame(                                            
   source = c('C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   57\\G   57 seed.jpg',
             'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   76\\G   76 seed.jpg',
             'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   87\\G   87 seed.jpg',
             'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G   92\\G   92 seed.jpg',
             'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  148\\G  148 seed.jpg',
             'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  166\\G  166 seed.jpg',
             'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE2\\G  169\\G  169 seed.jpg'),
    destination = 
        c('C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed',                      
        'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed',              
        'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed',
        'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed',             
        'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed',
        'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed',
        'C:\\Users\\macosta\\Downloads\\CORE_NEW_ORDER\\P_Vulgaris\\seed')

      file.copy(from = df$source, to = file.path(df$destination,
      basename(df$source)))

      # destination  is the new folder.
   ```
7. For **P_Vulgaris** this are the files in `seed`.

[image]